# google map camera update according to compass direction

Tags: flutter

I am using this package `google_maps_flutter:`

Home to Move the camera like google map app according to compass and mobile movement

```
GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.hybrid,
        initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _controller.complete(controller);
        },
      )
```